# Creating/editing batch files in NetBeans

Tags: plugins, netbeans, batch-file, code-completion

I'd like to make/edit batch files in NetBeans IDE. Is there any standard feature or plugin for that? 
Want at least code highlighting, but Code Completion would be realy great.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think netbeans has a batch plugin but [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/) has code highlighting for batch.